# Ionic 3 with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, file, ionic3, file-structure

I am new to Ionic and even AngularJs. I have already some experiences with jQuery and PHP on the Serverside. Now I do like to create an Ionic App. The setup went well and also the first experimental "pages" were actually pretty fun to code. But more and more i see a on other Stackoverflow Q&A's that there is something like:

```
angular.module('someName', function(){
    //do stuff
});
// other example
.controller('Controller',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

I know there are the Pages and the app.module.ts and so on and it works perfectly without any `angular.module()`, but i have seen so many stack overflow questions where the answer was linked to something with `.controller()` or `$scope` or something else.

Now my answer (or more a request) is, that someone could please explain (really really easy please), how do I use this `angular.module()` or `$scope` and **where do i put the files** with this functions? How do i load this in **Ionic 3**? How is the **recommended filestructure**?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: ts belongs to angular 2, where $scope and all other stuff belongs to angular js. ambiguous !

Comment: Sorry for the wrong definition of my question. It is also really hard for me to differentiate between those versions. A more specific example of what i do like to use is the post-request with ionic [link here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-post-request/90648/2 "ionic framework").

Comment: I also want to use angular-gettext (for translations) and here is it also described with `angular.module()`. [See here](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/install/)

Comment: From my experience for Ionic3 you can go with angular4 .More over there is no scope after 1 . Use `ts` also  invoke everything using `service` and event specific thing you handle with` ionic3`.